# Как осуществить поиск файлов в указанном каталоге по времени создания?

Tags: c++, время, файловая-система

Подскажите как сделать поиск файлов в каталоге, созданных в конкретном промежутке времени, и вывод их названий на консоль?
Не могу найти такой функции для реализации

Буду очень признателен!

Answer (score 0):

Начиная с С++17 имеется `<filesystem>`, который умеет много гитик :) в этом смысле.

Просто список файлов в каталоге получается с помощью [`directory_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/directory_iterator) (или [`recursive_directory_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/recursive_directory_iterator), в зависимости от того, как вы хотите обрабатывать вложенные каталоги). Это по сути контейнер значений [`directory_entry`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/directory_entry), в которых есть поле [`last_write_time`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/directory_entry/last_write_time), нужное вам.

Так что просто собираете всю информацию и выбираете нужные файлы - примеры по указанным ссылкам содержат практически все, что вам надо.

Comment: не особо понял, не могли бы вы показать хотя бы малейший пример данного поиска по каталогу скажем C:\\ ?

Comment: `for(auto& p: std::filesystem::directory_iterator("C:\\")) std::cout << p.path() << "\n";`